# multiple regex/pattern validation Joi Hapi

Tags: javascript, regex, joi, hapi

Hi guys i want to make a mutiple regex validation with joi/hapi but i don't understand how to do it i already multiple try but no one works, I want the password minimun have 1 capital letter, 1 minus letter, 1 number and 1 special character here ones of my try:

```
const passwordValidation = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    password: Joi.string()
      .pattern(new RegExp('^[a-z]{1,}$'))
      .pattern(new RegExp('^[A- Z]{1,}$'))
      .pattern(new RegExp('^[0 - 9]{1,}'))
      .pattern(new RegExp('^[!@#$%&*]{1,}'))
      .min(8)
      .required()
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};
```

and

```
const passwordValidation = (data) => {
  const schema = Joi.object({
    password: Joi.string()
      .regex('^[a-z]{1,}$')
      .regex('^[A- Z]{1,}$')
      .regex('^[0 - 9]{1,}')
      .regex('^[!@#$%&*]{1,}')
      .min(8)
      .required()
  });
  return schema.validate(data);
};
```

how i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`regex()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectregex) requires the object to be a RegExp object.

And fixes in regex

https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors

**Working Demo**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7c78r7?file=index.js